# Scoring Answers based on Text in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I'm looking for an Excel formula that will take the values found in column A, B, and C and calculate them based on the scoring model below such as the sample result found in column D (The numbers are intentionally negative)

An additional issue is the data presents with the semi-colons. The semi-colons present after each listen type except the last in the list in any cell. I tried Vlookup and it did not satisfy my needs. I had seen some CountA solutions on the Microsoft forum but it was for a Yes/No situation, not multiple variables to score differently.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think row 2 should be `-40`, `-5+-5+-10+-10+-10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUM(), XLOOKUP(), TEXTJOIN(), and TEXTSPLIT():

```
=SUM(XLOOKUP(TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,A2:C2),";")),$A$11:$A$14,$B$11:$B$14,0))
```

[image]

OR:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS($B$11:$B$14,$A$11:$A$14,TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,A2:C2),";"))))
```

[image]

Comment: This worked superbly. It looks like i forgot to mention one thing, the data also encompasses blank values, i need those blank values to = 0 in the event that there are blanks across all three days. otherwise i'm getting some results while other rows are bringing back  #VALUE!

Comment: Change the `TRUE` to `FALSE` and it should work

Comment: BTW, `TRIM()` can be excluded : `=SUM(SUMIFS($B$11:$B$14,$A$11:$A$14,TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,A2:C2),{";"," "})))`

Comment: Scott Sir nice formula with `XLOOKUP()` and `SUMIFS()` but I think `SUMIFS()` is more cleaner! Also when I remove the `TRIM()` it doesnt require the `error` check for blanks.